# If there some alternatives to CloudFlare proxy for server ip hiding?

Tags: dns, reverse-proxy, amazon-cloudfront, cloudflare

i need some alternatives to CloudFlare proxying option for hiding server ip of my domains.
What another servise can do this? Maybe some CloudFront settings or anithing else?
Tnx!

Comment: What is your backend like? That are plenty of reverse-proxy systems you can build into your app architecture. This would allow your to obfuscate your ip on a custom server, rather than relying on Cloudlfare

Comment: @TaylorCochran , just simple php sites with Apache. CF is comfortable for some unification and its reverse-proxy gives me that without buying a lot of servers just for that function. So, maybe you no some cheap services that gives reverse-proxy functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want free solutions, here are a few that come to mind.

- DDoS-Guard - A lot of sites use this as a Cloudflare proxy alternative, but recently their free plan has popped off their site. It didn't have any strict/hard limits. It may come back, so have put it here if it's temporary.
- OVH SSL Gateway - Haven't heard there being any limitations either, this one is open to the public for free. Has 2 proxy locations currently.
- G-Core Labs - Up to 1TB bandwidth/month for free, a lot of PoPs.
- YAKUCAP - Up to 1TB/month bandwidth free.
- Bitmitigate - Up to 100GB+/month website traffic and protected bandwidth, free.
- ArvanCloud - Up to 100 GB Traffic/mo, but country availability limited.
- Namecheap's FREE CDN - up to 50GB/mo traffic.
- Hostry's Global CDN - 39 PoPs, up to 10GB/mo traffic with an overusage charge.

Self-hosted/other solutions that come to mind, if your not a fan of using provided services.

- Oracle provides 24GB RAM ARM VPS as part of their free plan, with various limitations (involves network limitations). Could host things using Oracle, as traffic is DDoS protected. Doesn't necessarily hide your IP, but you could use the IP on the VPS to act as a proxy to your actual webserver.
- Self-hosted DNS (isn't recommended due to uptime, anycast networks that cover the DNS, etc) - had a brief look, https://github.com/DNSCrypt/dnscrypt-proxy is one option, providing a secure self-hosted DNS. Seems like it's updated recently which may be what people are looking for.